# jquery slideonlyone call function after first is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I am looking for some assistance with calling a function after the first has been completed. I'm pretty new to jquery in general and am having some difficulty getting this to work.

The code below is what I have right now, which is currently working for just the 'slideonlyone' jquery plugin. What I would like to do is have the slideonlyone function work as usual and then once that reveals the div, i would like the page to scroll down (or up depending on placement) to the top of the div being revealed, since some of them are images and may show up awkwardly on the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
    $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).slideDown(600);
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(600);
          }
     });
}
</script>
```

The HTML for the anchor tag looks like this...not sure if thats really needed though.

```
<a href="javascript:slideonlyone('newboxes11');">
    <div class="project">
       <img src="image.png" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From the second example of [**.slideDown()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/#entry-examples), you would modify `slideonlyone` as follows

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone, domeafter) {
    var mdomeafter = function () {};
    if (domeafter !== undefined && typeof domeafter === 'function') mdomeafter = domeafter;
    $('.newboxes2').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) $(this).slideDown(600, mdomeafter);
          else $(this).slideUp(600, mdomeafter);
     });
}
```

and some function for `domeafter` as a second argument in your link.

Answer (score 0):

I might be reading your question incorrectly, but if you want something to occur after the slideUp or slideDown animations finish then all you need to do is supply a call back function as a part of the call to slideUp/slideDown. So for example

```
$(this).slideDown(600, function() { 
  do something when slide down finishes
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/ for more info on the slideUp function.

Answer (score 0):

check this JsFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vvWyQ/2/) it's simple and maybe it will help you